How To Compare Two Columns in Same Table?
I have two tables with this structure:
First table: Document



Doc_Num
Doc_Type
Doc_Date
Doc_Valide




BLA241913
BLA
01/07/2024
1



Second table: DocumentD



Doc_Num
DocDOrigine




BLA241913
CMA241682



I try many queries with self join, inner join, left join but did not get desired result.
My query:
SELECT *
FROM Documentd 
INNER JOIN [Document] ON DocumentD.Doc_Num = [Document].Doc_Num 
WHERE ([Document].Doc_Type IN (N'bla', N'faca'))
  AND (DocumentD.DocD_QReliquat >= 0) 
  AND ([Document].Doc_Date BETWEEN '2024-07-01' AND '2024-07-31')

This query return as result:



Doc_Num
Doc_Type
Doc_Date
DocDOrigine
Doc_Valide




BLA241913
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241682
1


BLA241913
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241682
1


BLA241913
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241682
1


BLA241914
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241683
1


BLA241914
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241683
1


BLA241915
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241684
1


BLA241916
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241685
1


BLA241917
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241686
0


ACHAT240730008
FACA
01/07/2024
BLA241913
2


ACHAT240730008
FACA
01/07/2024
BLA241913
2


ACHAT240730008
FACA
01/07/2024
BLA241913
0


ACHAT240730010
FACA
01/07/2024
BLA241914
0


ACHAT240730010
FACA
01/07/2024
BLA241914
1


ACHAT240731025
FACA
01/07/2024
null
1



I want to show all [Document].Doc_num with [Document].Doc_Type = 'BLA' and [Document].Doc_Valide = 1 , with condition this Documents not exist in DocDOrigine with [Document].Doc_Type = 'FACA' like this:



Doc_Num
Doc_Type
Doc_Date
DocDOrigine
Doc_Valide




BLA241915
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241684
1


BLA241916
BLA
01/07/2024
CMA241685
1



I wish I had been clear in posing my question, and I am here to clarify thank you.
Link : https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=e31a94d2-3778-4861-870f-7b0c6730a7d7

Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

I know, but is a same behavior :)

"I know, but is a same behavior" that isn't a reason to tag irrelevant products. A Playstation and an Xbox are both game consoles, and behave the same for many games that they both have, but I wouldn't take a Playstation to Microsoft and expect them to be able to diagnose problems with it. MySQL and SQL Server are entirely different products; that they are both (R)DBMS products doesn't make them "the same".

MSSQL / MysQL stuff aside, it would be very helpful to have example data from each table, and an expected result set.  My best guess what you're after is to compare two different rows from the same table, which would require giving one or both of those table references an alias so that they can be differentiated in the rest of the query.  See the "Using an Alias with a self-Join" section of https://learnsql.com/blob/sql-alias.  If you update your question with better sample data, we can give more specific recommendations.

Exemple : https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=e31a94d2-3778-4861-870f-7b0c6730a7d7

I think I understand the question.  I'm not sure if this is the right answer, but it returns the records you specified.
select *
from Document
where 
  Document.Doc_Num not in (select DocDOrigine from DocumentD) and
  Doc_Type = 'BLA' and
  Doc_Valide = 1;

Basically, the first WHERE clause is what you were missing.  This is one of the easiest ways to write that, but it could easily have performance issues or need its own filtering to match better with the Document table.
Here's another way it can be done, using an outer join instead of a sub-query:
select Document.* 
from Document
  left outer join DocumentD on
    Document.Doc_Num = DocumentD.DocDOrigine
where
  DocumentD.DocDOrigine is null and
  Document.Doc_Type = 'BLA' and
  Document.Doc_Valide = 1;


Edit:
I missed the DocDOrigine column from the example result set.  I had to add some missing data from your question to the SQL fiddle to get it to return the expected result set.  The SQL Fiddle link is:
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=8af184de-67b4-49cf-a4fe-50148dc9b4eb
The queries to return that are:
select
  Document.Doc_Num,
  Document.Doc_Type,
  Document.Doc_Date,
  DocumentD.DocDOrigine,
  Document.Doc_Valide
from Document
  inner join DocumentD on
    Document.Doc_Num = DocumentD.Doc_Num
where 
  Document.Doc_Num not in (select DocDOrigine from DocumentD) and
  Doc_Type = 'BLA' amd
  Doc_Valide = 1;

And, the outer join variant:
select
  Document.Doc_Num,
  Document.Doc_Type,
  Document.Doc_Date,
  PrimDocument.DocDOrigine,
  Document.Doc_Valide
from Document
  left outer join DocumentD as OrigDocument on
    Document.Doc_Num = OrigDocument.DocDOrigine
  inner join DocumentD as PrimDocument on
    Document.Doc_Num = PrimDocument.Doc_Num
WHERE
  OrigDocument.DocDOrigine is null and
  Document.Doc_Type = 'BLA' and
  Document.Doc_Valide = 1;

